# How to retrieve child with the immediate parent documents from MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to filter child documents from a MongoDB collection. Along with the child documents trying to fetch corresponding immediate parent documents as well.

```
**My parent document:**

{ "id":"123", "source":"02", "child":{"id":"456"}}

**My child document:**

{ "id":"456", "source":"01", "parent":{"id":"123"}}
```

How to fetch the child documents along with its corresponding parent documents dynamically?

Comment: Are they both in the same collection?

Comment: @Arsen Davtyan  Yes both are in the same collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilise [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation pipeline stage to perform a left outer join to the same collection (unsharded). Given your example documents, to retrieve children of parent document(s):

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([
       {"$match": {"child": {"$exists": 1} } }, 
       {"$lookup":{
            "from": "collectionA", 
            "localField": "id", 
            "foreignField": "parent.id", 
            "as": "children"}
        }
]);
```

To retrieve parent from child document(s):

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([
       {"$match": {"parent": {"$exists": 1} } }, 
       {"$lookup":{
            "from": "collectionA", 
            "localField": "id", 
            "foreignField": "child.id", 
            "as": "parent"}
        }
]);
```

I'd also recommend reviewing [MongoDB Model Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/), especially:

- [Model Tree Structures with Parent References](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/)
- [Model Tree Structures with Child References](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-child-references/)